# Rotate PDF file in WebView using XCode

Tags: ios, dictionary

I created an iOS App with XCode. There is a WebView containing a PDF file. I'm able to zoom in, zoom out and move the file on the screen.

Now I want to make the PDF file rotate. This is a street map and it would be useful if I could turn it. Like in the Apples own iOS Map, there I can turn the map in all directions.

Comment: like turn PDF 180 % ie opposite of it or you mean anything different

Comment: Not only 90°, 180°, 270° and 360°. Better would be 1°, 2°, 3°, 4°…395°, 360°. Just like in the iPhone Map from Apple. How can I do that? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be using `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotateGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];

[yourRotatingView addGestureRecognizer:rotateGesture];
```

Its method defination:

```
- (IBAction)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
  recognizer.rotation = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where do I have to add the first code? In ViewController.h? The second code in ViewController.m, right?

Comment: Add both code in ViewController.m, first in viewDidLoad() method and second one paste this method below viewDidLoad() method. Note  yourRotatingView (may your webview which has PDF File) means the view you want to rotate that need to be changed. Hope you have understood what i meant here.